# Use XElement as array of XElements and access them

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to ask if it is possible to use XElement as array... There is sample how I created that and use that.

```
XElement[] tracks = new XElement[pauses.Count + 1];

tracks[0].Add(Trackpoint)
```

Unfortunately it throws exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ***.exe. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It is quite obvious that I can't do this this way. Is there any another solution how could I do this?

Comment: Begs the question: Why not make tracks an `XElement` and append child `XElement`s? Or just use a `List<XElement>` (See [Arrays simply do not model any problem that I have at all well](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized the `array`, but all elements are `null`. Add a reference to a new `XElement` at each index before using it.